# Google sign-in provider without ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-identity

Following the example from Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0 for using the Google sign-in provider, I get an error stating that there is no DefaultSignInScheme.

This is however set in the AddAuthentication method, so I don't see what I'm missing.

The error occurs in the signin-google page after being redirected back to the webapplication from Google.

As far as I can see, I'm following the example to every detail.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can modify the code like this?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Anuraj, I'll try that later today and post the results.

Comment: Using options.DefaultScheme instead of options.DefaultAuthenticationScheme did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This approach also solved the issue (setting SignInScheme)

```
options.ClientId = configuration["Google:ClientId"];
options.ClientSecret = configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```